# Kafka Android issue

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm not able to use Kafka producer in Android app. I'm getting the below exception.,

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.management.DynamicMBean" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.a.kafkaproducer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-zookeeper-3.4.6_8a38f89467d40a18afbd8baad7b29088157e6083-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.a.kafkaproducer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-zkclient-0.8_e811ffc59b2b86f143b12056ea3479df3f628d5a-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.a.kafkaproducer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-25.1.0_c6c37b5425fad5a782cbe7db2279266099bc29a9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.a.kafkaproducer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-snappy-java-1.1.2.6_848c76c3e0ca3a9ed4d0c95a6eeba1e11cd43625-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.a.kafkaproducer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.a.kafkaproducer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.a.kafkaproducer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file



`at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class 
com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile) (DexFile.java:-2)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:296)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:289)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(java.lang.String, java.util.List) (DexPathList.java:418)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:367)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:367)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/art:     at void org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer) (KafkaProducer.java:223)
I/art:     at void org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(java.util.Properties) (KafkaProducer.java:188)
I/art:     at void com.nokia.kafkaproducer.Producer.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean) (Producer.java:29)
I/art:     at void com.nokia.kafkaproducer.MainActivity$1.onClick(android.view.View) (MainActivity.java:35)
I/art:     at boolean android.view.View.performClick() (View.java:5637)
I/art:     at void android.view.View$PerformClick.run() (View.java:22429)
I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:751)
I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:95)
I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)`
```

Using following Gradle dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients
compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version:     '0.10.1.1'  testCompile 'junit:junit:3.8.1' }
```

I'm using Producer example from this [Github repo](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples)

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Please post the `dependencies` block of your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice added gradle dependency block

Answer (score 0):

The kafka clients library is developed against Java Standard Edition, which `javax.management` package is a part of. However, this package is not part of the Dalvik runtime that Android uses and which only provides a subset of the Java SE APIs. You will need to find a JAR file which contains the classes used by Kafka and put it in the `libs`  file of your project.

Answer (score -3):

> Enter it in your build gradle

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22
             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Can you please explain more about how this will solve the problem?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice in Logcat i saw the dex error so multidex enabled solve the problem.if am wrong please let me know

Comment: Why will multidex solve the problem? You should quote the part of the error which you think is important and explain what caused the problem. This will help others understand your solution.